# Laravel - Using a nested relationship with the query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an API but its starting to get a bit slow now that the data is increasing. I am moving some of the queries so that they use the DB query builder.

I have my last one which has a nested query:

```
$artists = Artist::with('performances', 'performances.stage')->get();
```

I have got so far:

```
$artists = \DB::table('artists')
    ->leftJoin('performances', 'artists.id', '=', 'performances.artist_id')
    ->get();
```

But now need to do the second relationship which in the Performance model is:

```
public function stage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Stage', 'id', 'stage_id');
}
```

Any help on how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use eloquent relationship with query builder like this

```
$artists = Artist::join('performances', 'artists.id', '=', 'performances.artist_id')
          ->all();


foreach($artists as $artist){
    $data = $artist->stage()->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very well covered in the official documentation, please, refer to this section of [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

I think that you want to achieve something like this:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

And also, please, read carefully [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

Comment: I have read the docs, but cannot understand how to do the relationship like i need to with the nested join.